# flatten nested object using lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

flatten, flattenDeep or flattenDepth of lodash only accept array. How to flatten nested object?

```
var data = {
  "dates": {
    "expiry_date": "30 sep 2018",
    "available": "30 sep 2017",
    "min_contract_period": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "1 month",
      "value": false
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "2 months",
      "value": true
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "3 months",
      "value": false
    }]
  },
  "price": {
    "curreny": "RM",
    "min": 1500,
    "max": 2000
  }
}
```

I want nested property to be the first level, like expiry_date should be level 1, not within dates, and I think dates should be gone, it's not needed anymore. I can do it manually, use map() but I'm looking to use lodash to ease the task.

Comment: could you give example code of how you want the output to look after the task is completed? saying level 1 and that things 'should be gone' can confuse the issue where an example would be very clear

Comment: This question was asked/functionality proposed in [lodash#1228](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1228) with the proposed "solution" to check out the [`flat` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat#flatten-original-options)

Answer (score 21):

One of the easiest solutions would be, merging the nested object with parent,

```
_.merge(data, data.dates);
```

This will bring all `data.dates` property into `data`. Then delete `data.dates`

```
delete data.dates
```

Comment: I searched for a few hours to find a simple, sensible and intuitive way to do this, and this is by the far the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

ES6 version:

```js
var data = {
  "dates": {
    "expiry_date": "30 sep 2018",
    "available": "30 sep 2017",
    "min_contract_period": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "1 month",
      "value": false
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "2 months",
      "value": true
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "3 months",
      "value": false
    }]
  },
  "price": {
    "curreny": "RM",
    "min": 1500,
    "max": 2000
  }
};

var {dates: {expiry_date, ...dates}, ...rest} = data;
var flatData = {dates, expiry_date, ...rest}
console.log(flatData)
```

One thing to note is that you have to be careful with deeply nested destructuting. In this example if `data.dates` is `undefined` and you'll try to destructure it, error will be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You can [*.merge()*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) the result of [.get()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) and [_.pick()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick):

```js
var data = {"dates": {"expiry_date": "30 sep 2018","available": "30 sep 2017","min_contract_period": [{"id": 1,"name": "1 month","value": false}, {"id": 2,"name": "2 months","value": true}, {"id": 3,"name": "3 months","value": false}]},"price": {"curreny": "RM","min": 1500,"max": 2000}},
    result = _.merge(_.get(data, 'dates'), _.pick(data, 'price'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5934567/andrey)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478730/10372580)

```
function flattenObject(o, prefix = '', result = {}, keepNull = true) {
  if (_.isString(o) || _.isNumber(o) || _.isBoolean(o) || (keepNull && _.isNull(o))) {
    result[prefix] = o;
    return result;
  }

  if (_.isArray(o) || _.isPlainObject(o)) {
    for (let i in o) {
      let pref = prefix;
      if (_.isArray(o)) {
        pref = pref + `[${i}]`;
      } else {
        if (_.isEmpty(prefix)) {
          pref = i;
        } else {
          pref = prefix + '.' + i;
        }
      }
      flattenObject(o[i], pref, result, keepNull);
    }
    return result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an existing solution you can use a library called [flat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat), as it said in [this lodash github issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1228#issuecomment-105249629)

Comment: This is the ideal solution for flattening the object. Thanks you @ilyavysotski

Answer (score 1):

this flattens object with nested objects and arrays of any depth. keys in resulting object are full paths to properties in input object

```
public static flattenObject(o: any, prefix?: string, result?: any): any {

    prefix = prefix ? prefix : '';
    result = result ? result : {};

    if (_.isString(o) || _.isNumber(o) || _.isBoolean(o)) {
        result[prefix] = o;
        return result;
    }

    if (_.isArray(o) || _.isPlainObject(o)) {
        for (let i in o) {

            let pref = prefix;
            if (_.isArray(o)) {
                pref = pref + `[${i}]`;
            } else {
                if (_.isEmpty(prefix)) {
                    pref = i;
                } else {
                    pref = prefix + '.' + i;
                }
            }

            Utils.flattenObject(o[i], pref, result);
        }
        return result;
    }


    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to flatten the whole object, not only its "dates" property, something like this should work, you don't even need lodash:

```js
var data = {
  "dates": {
    "expiry_date": "30 sep 2018",
    "available": "30 sep 2017",
    "min_contract_period": [/*...*/]
  },
  "price": {
    "curreny": "RM",
    "min": 1500,
    "max": 2000
  }
};

const flattenedObj = flattenObject(data);
// {
//    "expiry_date": "30 sep 2018",
//    "available": "30 sep 2017",
//    "min_contract_period": [/*...*/],
//    "curreny": "RM",
//    "min": 1500,
//    "max": 2000
// }

function flattenObject(obj) {
  const result = {};

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    // if object (and not null!), merge it with the resulting object,
    // otherwise just copy the value
    if (val && typeof val === "object")
      Object.assign(result, val);
    else
      result[key] = val;
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hmm what is the value of obj and nestedObject in this example?

Comment: @AmandaKoster updated my solution to make it clearer. `obj` is just a function argument name, you're supposed to pass your original object when calling this function.